# tikz: problem with positioning

Tags: floats

I have read [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) carefully: however, I still have problems with the placement of figures and tables inside a document. Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand\ProvideMathOperator[2]{\ifdefined#1\else\DeclareMathOperator{#1}{#2}\fi}
\ProvideMathOperator{\w}{w}
\ProvideMathOperator{\x}{x}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1][1]}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=0,ymax=80,
  ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70},
  xtick={0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30}, 
  extra y ticks={0},            % <---
  xmax=0.35,xmin=0,
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  minor tick num=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  axis on top,                  % <---
  xlabel=$\x_1$,ylabel=$\theta\lbrack\si{\celsius}\rbrack$,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed relative,
                     },
               ]
  \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0.05,32.05)(0.10,30.00)(0.15,32.4)(0.20,35.65)(0.25,42.50)(0.31,63.45)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\textcolor{yellow}{\lipsum[1][1]}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]    
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=0,ymax=80,
  ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70},
  xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70}, 
  extra y ticks={0},            % <---
  xmax=80,xmin=0,
  extra x ticks={0},            % <---
  minor tick num=1,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,                   % <---
  axis on top,                  % <---
  xlabel=$\w_1$,ylabel=$\theta\lbrack\si{\celsius}\rbrack$,
  x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed relative,
                     },
               ]
  \addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={draw=blue,fill=orange},smooth]
    coordinates {
    (25.97,32.05)(42.55,30.00)(53.99,32.4)(62.50,35.65)(68.96,42.50)(74.85,63.45)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[1][1]}
\end{document}
```

Red text should be above the first graph whole

Yellow text should be between the graphs whole

Blue text should be below the second graph whole

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide in your question mwe (minimal working example), a code for the complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem. given link can be after while death and no one will be able to see what is your problem. for text use some dummy text (from `lipsum` or `blindtext` ...). explain your problem relation to `tikz`. your question is not clear.

Comment: @Zarko question edited

Comment: Simply, leave space after each `\end{figure}`.

Answer (score 1):

In TeX a (not commented out) linebreak is equivalent to a space.
An empty line denotes the end of a paragraph.

Because you have no empty lines in your code TeX puts it all in one paragraph.

If you insert empty lines in between TeX will split the text up into several paragraphs and place the figures between those paragraphs.

Also, a few empty lines in your preamble might improve readability.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\ProvideMathOperator[2]{\ifdefined#1\else\DeclareMathOperator{#1}{#2}\fi}
\ProvideMathOperator{\w}{w}
\ProvideMathOperator{\x}{x}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\lipsum[1][1]}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid, grid style=dashed,
            ymin=0,ymax=80,
            ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70},
            xtick={0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.20,0.25,0.30}, 
            extra y ticks={0},            % <---
            xmax=0.35,xmin=0,
            extra x ticks={0},            % <---
            minor tick num=1,
            axis lines = middle,
            set layers,                   % <---
            axis on top,                  % <---
            xlabel=$\x_1$,ylabel=$\theta\lbrack\si{\celsius}\rbrack$,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed relative},
        ]
            \addplot+[color=red,mark=*,mark options={draw=red,fill=green},smooth] coordinates {
                (0.05,32.05)(0.10,30.00)(0.15,32.4)(0.20,35.65)(0.25,42.50)(0.31,63.45)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\textcolor{yellow}{\lipsum[1][1]}

\begin{figure}[htbp]    
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid, grid style=dashed,
            ymin=0, ymax=80,
            ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70},
            xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70}, 
            extra y ticks={0},            % <---
            xmax=80,xmin=0,
            extra x ticks={0},            % <---
            minor tick num=1,
            axis lines = middle,
            set layers,                   % <---
            axis on top,                  % <---
            xlabel=$\w_1$,ylabel=$\theta\lbrack\si{\celsius}\rbrack$,
            x label style={at={(1,0)},right},
            y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed relative},
        ]
            \addplot+[color=blue,mark=*,mark options={draw=blue,fill=orange},smooth] coordinates {
                (25.97,32.05)(42.55,30.00)(53.99,32.4)(62.50,35.65)(68.96,42.50)(74.85,63.45)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\textcolor{blue}{\lipsum[1][1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]